# counting 1's in a bit string to keep positions in a variable and then accessing each value

Tags: python, dataframe, bit-manipulation, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

> I am finding 1's in a bit string and then storing them.

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Sample code:**

```
def indices(chromosome):
    return {i for i,c in enumerate(chromosome) if c=='1'}

for ind in df_initial_pop['initial_pop'].index:
    locations = indices(df_initial_pop['initial_pop'] [ind])
    print (locations)
```

**Output:**

```
{32, 29, 31}
{8, 34, 23}
{34, 35, 31}
{17, 14, 31}
{26, 19, 34}
```

Now, I want to access `32, 29, and 31` and store each of them in a separate variable. **Is it possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible, but using individual variables implies that the number of elements in your set is fixed.

```
s = {32, 29, 31}
a,b,c = s
# Now a=32, b=29, c=31
```